# Constrained Spline Function in r

Tags: r, spline, exponential

hope all is well.

I have been exploring a few options for constraining a spline function so that it not only stays positive, but, so that it stays above the lowest value of y in the dataframe. I am assuming there is a penalized spline function out there where one can readily adapt the shape, though I have not found easily or tried yet. I have also tried nls with an exponential decay function which works, however, the last estimated point is much higher than desired (would like it to pass through, or be closer to the final value of y). see code below with the options i have tried. The ultimate goal however is to fit a spline that passes through all points and never decreases below the lowest value of y at any point while also acknowledging that yes there are only 5 data points. thanks in advance for the help.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(gnm)
library(cobs)
library(zoo)

DF <- data.frame(x = seq(1,5,1),y=c(26419753,9511111,3566667,57993,52194))
t=1:5

# option 1a and 1b: preferred method which is fitting a spline function
mod1a <- splinefun(DF$x,DF$y)
curve(mod1a, 1,5)
pred_interval_mod1a <- seq(1,5,length = 40)
interp(pred_interval_mod1a)   # has that dip to negative near the end which should remain larger than y= 52,194

mod1b <- cobs(x= DF$x,y = DF$y,pointwise=rbind(c(0,52194,-1),c(0,26419753,1)))
pred_interval_mod1b <- seq(1,5,length = 40)
interp(pred_interval_mod1b)


# option 2: NLS for exponential decay with starting values
mod2 <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(t, yf, y0, log_alpha), data = DF)
qplot(t, y, data = augment(mod2)) + geom_line(aes(y = .fitted))

# option 3: similar NLS premise but with lower defined
mod3 <- nls(y ~ yf + (y0 - yf) * exp(-alpha * t), data = DF,
            start = list(y0 = 26419753, yf = 52194, alpha = 1),
            lower= c(-Inf,52194,-Inf),algorithm="port")

# option 4: similar to 2 and 3 
a=log(52194)
mod4 <- gnm(y ~ Exp(1 + t) -1, verbose = FALSE, constrain="Exp(.+x).Intercept",
constrainTo=a, start=c(a,-0.05), data=DF)
mod4_df <- data.frame(t = seq(1,5,by=1))
mod4_pred <- predict(mod4,newdata=mod4_df)
mod4_pred
```

Comment: have found a workaround for this particular application but am still curious in creating this in spline form. have messed with weights and the scam package but nothing produces the results comparable to na_interpolation and the "stine" method within the imputeTS package

Comment: In the bivariate setting, there is the paper L. L. Schumaker, H. Speleers, Nonnegativity preserving macro-element interpolation of scattered data, _Computer Aided Geometric Design_ **27** (3) (2010) 245–261 ([preprint](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/schumake/pos.pdf)). Maybe one can try and build something similar for your (univariate) data.